# "Today I learnt..." vs. "Today I have learnt..."

Tags: verbs, tenses

My friend asked me:

> What have you learnt today?

Can I reply:

> Today I learnt...

Or should I say:

> Today I have learnt...

I think both are correct.

Can I say "today I learnt"  while the day hasn't ended yet and I know that I won't be learning more today, or do I have to reply using the same construction "today I have learnt" as was in the question?

Comment: I was obviously outvoted on the closevote reasons, but I still think this should be migrated to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), not left here to fester / languish.

Comment: Note that "learnt" is not idiomatic in (most of) the US.  You would use "learned".

Answer (score 2):

'Today I  learnt' is more appropriate as we are not taking about an event that has just happened but is in the process of occuring.

Note perfect tense is used to describe events that have just been completed.